# Sharepoint Hosted App is not accessible after deployment

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Appreciate your help for the below:

I am trying to create a sample sharepoint hosted app which has nothing more than the create by VS by default, but I after deploying it to sharepoint when trying click the link for the app I am getting a prompt to enter user name and password, even I am logged in to sharepoint host web, after entering the same sharepoint account details I am still not able to access the app

Please note that I have created a new entry in my hosts file "127.0.0.1 apps.machinename",
 a and configured a that app domain in sharepoint

below are the request/response happened from fiddler:

GEThttp://machinename.com/sites/development/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id={75458E14-4E03-4D50-B961-17110638C0B0} HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Refererhttp://machinename.com/sites/development/_layouts/15/start.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: machinename.com
Cookie: databaseBtnText=Open%20with%20Access; databaseBtnDesc=Works%20with%20items%20in%20a%20Microsoft%20Access%20database%2E; WSS_FullScreenMode=false

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 270b649c-3afa-502a-3ed2-45f5f646158b
request-id: 270b649c-3afa-502a-3ed2-45f5f646158b
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 3
SPIisLatency: 1
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2013 10:49:07 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

401 UNAUTHORIZED

---

GEThttp://machinename.com/sites/development/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id={75458E14-4E03-4D50-B961-17110638C0B0} HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Refererhttp://machinename.com/sites/development/_layouts/15/start.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Cookie: databaseBtnText=Open%20with%20Access; databaseBtnDesc=Works%20with%20items%20in%20a%20Microsoft%20Access%20database%2E; WSS_FullScreenMode=false
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==
Host: machinename.com

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADgAOADgAAAAVgoriM+REraoBMzMAAAAAAAAAAFgAWABGAAAABgGxHQAAAA9BAFUAQgBGAE0AMAAyAAIADgBBAFUAQgBGAE0AMAAyAAEADgBBAFUAQgBGAE0AMAAyAAQADgBBAFUAQgBGAE0AMAAyAAMADgBBAFUAQgBGAE0AMAAyAAcACADLDSQaKALPAQAAAAA=
SPRequestGuid: 270b649c-aafa-502a-3ed2-468e3ff0cf47
request-id: 270b649c-aafa-502a-3ed2-468e3ff0cf47
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 1
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2013 10:49:07 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

---

GEThttp://machinename.com/sites/development/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id={75458E14-4E03-4D50-B961-17110638C0B0} HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Refererhttp://machinename.com/sites/development/_layouts/15/start.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Cookie: databaseBtnText=Open%20with%20Access; databaseBtnDesc=Works%20with%20items%20in%20a%20Microsoft%20Access%20database%2E; WSS_FullScreenMode=false
Host: machinename.com
Authorization: Negotiate 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

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location:http://app-4e7c4c2314d408.apps.machinename.com/sites/development/SharePointApp4/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fmachinename.com%2Fsites%2Fdevelopment&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4420%2E1017&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp%2D4e7c4c2314d408%2Eapps%2Emachinename.com%2Fsites%2Fdevelopment%2FSharePointApp4
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
SPRequestGuid: 270b649c-dafa-502a-3ed2-4eb908b92e72
request-id: 270b649c-dafa-502a-3ed2-4eb908b92e72
SPRequestDuration: 29
SPIisLatency: 0
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2013 10:49:07 GMT
Content-Length: 448

Object moved

### Object moved to here.

---

GEThttp://app-4e7c4c2314d408.apps.machinename.com/sites/development/SharePointApp4/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fmachinename.com%2Fsites%2Fdevelopment&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4420%2E1017&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp%2D4e7c4c2314d408%2Eapps%2Emachinename.com%2Fsites%2Fdevelopment%2FSharePointApp4 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://machinename.com/sites/development/_layouts/15/start.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: app-4e7c4c2314d408.apps.machinename.com

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 270b649c-dafc-502a-3ed2-4988e98d8356
request-id: 270b649c-dafc-502a-3ed2-4988e98d8356
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 8
SPIisLatency: 0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2013 10:49:07 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

401 UNAUTHORIZED

---